How to add custom style to w3m-button from @walletconnect/modal package?
I have this code where I use w3m-button from @walletconnect/modal package.
export default function ConnectButton() {
  return <w3m-button />;
}

It is shown like this:

I wanted to add these style to that button.
.button {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 9px 16px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    background-color: #313743;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #434956;
}

Is it possible? I didn't saw any helpful information from the docs.
